# Two dimensional random variables and conditional pmf if $f(x)=24x^2, 0<x<\frac{1}{2} \text{ and} f(y|x=X)=\frac{y}{2x^2}, \text{ if} 0< y<2x$

Tags: probability, random-variables, marginal-probability

My solution:

$$f_Y=\int^{0.5}_{0.5y}12y dx=\left. 12xy \right|^{0.5}_{0.5y}=6y-6y^2$$

$$f(x|Y=y)=\frac{12y}{6y(1-y)}=\frac{2}{1-y}$$

In general, I think I don't understand what I have to do at all. Can anyone assist?

Comment: Any further questions?

Comment: It looks good. In my opinion there is no need to delete your previous question/work.

Comment: The notations in the body are meaningless.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you have written $f_{X,Y}(x,y)=f_X(x)\cdot f_{Y|X}(x,y)$. The notation is not always uniformly. In a simplified way $f_X$, $f(x)$ and $f_X(x)$ have the same meaning. They represents the pdf of the random variable $X$.

For calculation we can input the terms:

$$f_{X,Y}(x,y)=24x^2\cdot \frac{y}{2x^2}=12y$$

From this result we can re-calculate $f_X(x)$ by integrating. For this purpose we need the bounds for y. We know that $y<2x$ and we also know that $0<y$

$$f_X(x)=\int_{0}^{2x} 12y \, dy=...$$

To calculate $f_Y(y)$ you integrate $f_{X,Y}(x,y)$ as well. We know that $y<2x$ and therefore $\frac12y<x<0.5$

$$f_Y(y)=\int_{\frac12y}^{0.5} 12y \, dx=...$$

Comment: I didn't understand how you came up with the last bound. It is given that $0<x$ why do you make a bound with $y$ instead of $0$?

Comment: In general at $f_X(x)$ the bounds of x are numbers only (similar for $f_Y(y)$). Thus from here you cannot get any bounds for $x$ in terms of $y$. So you have to look around if there are any other information if $x$ is restricted by $y$. This bound can be found at the conditional function.

Comment: But what if in this instance $\frac{1}{2}y$ is grater than zero, doesn't that give a wrong solution?

Comment: No, it doesn´t. $x=\frac12y$  is greater than zero as well: $x>0$.

Comment: Yes, but if it's an integral, I was wondering whether the fact that the values are not equal cause a loss of the integrable area, if that makes sense?

Comment: You mean we have $x>\frac12y$ instead of  $x\geq \frac12y$?

Comment: @calcullus I have a silly quesetion. Why does the bounds for $f(y|X=x)$ are the same as for $f_Y$?

Comment: @calcullus Now I did the calculation for $f(x|Y=y)$ and wanted to be sure that my solution is correct.

Comment: @user In general we have the bounds $0<y<2x$ and $0 <x < \frac{1}{2}$. Usually these bounds are stated with the joint pdf $f_{X,Y}(x,y)$. But here the joint pdf is not given. So one bound is stated at $f_X(x)$ and the other at $f(y|X=x)$. But both bounds are have to be considered.

Comment: @calcullus One more question, why do we need to found bounds for $f_Y$ in terms of y, if we must integrate by x? Why can't we use the bounds given in the formulation of the task? $0<x<\frac{1}{2}$?

Comment: @user "why do we need to found bounds for $f_Y$ in terms of y" Because we want to find the pdf of $y$. This pdf depends on the variable $y$. And $x$ bounded as well by $y$.

Comment: ok, but then why couldn't we leave it as 0<y<2x?

Comment: @user You are integrating wrt $\color{red}x$-**not y**.